# Junit formatted test report

Tags: java, junit, ant, soapui

I am using this code for generating the junit report from SOAPUI test cases.

```
<target name="gen-reports">
      <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
         <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
         </fileset>
         <report todir="${test.reports}/Report"/>
      </junitreport>
</target>
```

`test.reports` is the folder where data is SOAPUI report is present. 
And report is generating properly. But on one page of error it looks like this:

[image: This is error image]

But in second and third errors it is showing the HTML tags not the html page. 
what is reason of this error?